# Processing files with C# in folders whose names contain spaces

Tags: c#

There are plenty of C# samples that show how to manipulate files and directories but they inevitably use folder paths that contain no spaces. In the real world I need to be able to process files in folders with names that contain spaces. I have written the code below which shows how I have solved the problem. However it doesn't seem to be very elegant and I wonder if anyone has a better way.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var dirPath = @args[0] +  "\\";

        string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*txt");
        foreach (var oldFile in myFiles)
        {
            string newFile = dirPath + "New " + Path.GetFileName(oldFile);
            File.Move(oldFile, newFile);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Regards,
Nigel Ainscoe

Comment: Use Path.Combine() instead of dealing with backslashes yourself...

Comment: Am I missing something?  All of the `System.IO` classes handle files and directories with spaces.  Technically even DOS did, in terms of the file system, it's just that certain command-line tools didn't parse the spaces properly.

Comment: Path.Combine is vital - you will get an error if you try and do the slashes yourself and won't realise until you try a file with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string newFile = Path.Combine(args[0], "New " + Path.GetFileName(oldFile));
```

or:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Directory
            .GetFiles(args[0], "*txt")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(oldFile => {
                var newFile = Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFile), 
                    "New " + Path.GetFileName(oldFile)
                );
                File.Move(oldFile, newFile);
            });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks much more like what I was after Darin. Thank you.

Comment: Now I just need to check the user passed path doesn't contain a trailing backslash else it crashes